# ViewPager as a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

So in my android application, I am currently using viewpager as well as fragments. What I am trying to do is start off the application using a viewpager, which is a fragment itself, that contains three fragments. The third fragment in the viewpager has a button, when clicked on will replace the viewpager fragment with another fragment. I press the button, and the viewpager fragment is replaced with the other fragment ok. But when I press the back button, it returns to the viewpager fragment, but all I see it a blank screen. What should happen is that I should see the third fragment in the viewpager. I think what is happening is that when I press the back button, it goes back to the viewpager, but does not load the fragments in the viewpager. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Are you using `getChildFragmentManager()` when setting up your `PagerAdapter` containing fragments?

Comment: Just a thought, as far as I know fragments inside fragments is a bad idea in Android.

Comment: Its not a bad idea if you listen to what commonsware said...

Comment: Are you using  `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(
                        android.R.id.content, new MyFrag()).addToBackStack(MyFrag.class.getName()).commit();` for your committing? Backstack is important to get back.

Comment: I am using addToBackStack and also tried using getChildFragmentManager. The problem with getChildFragmentManager is that I can't launch the fragment from the button press because that fragment is not in the viewpager.